# Javascript 'undefined' error in IE8- only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

My script at http://www.mincovlaw.com/interest/calculate is working fine in FF, Chrome, Safari and IE9.

I've just realized that it throws an `'newamount' is undefined` error in IE8.

Any idea why that may be happening?

Comment: Post your code here, tell us what do we need to do to reproduce the Error.

Comment: Care to share the problem code?

Comment: Paste your code here instead of redirecting us to your website...

Comment: I'm not trying to promote the website. I don't understand what it is that IE doesn't like about the code. There are over 800 lines in the code. Should I post them all?

Comment: @UnoMeinAme No. Only the *relevant* code. If you don't know what the relevant code is then that's your problem

Comment: I think I see that the problem is being caused by one line: `province=document.getElementById('province');` Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: i changed the var name to province1 and the problem is gone. any idea why that was causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

**First**, you have a script error that you should fix.

```
window.onload=changeaboutfirm(1);
```

The `onload` event should be bound directly to a reference to a function, not to whatever `changeaboutfirm()` returns.  You probably want something like:

```
window.onload = function () { changeaboutfirm(1); }
```

In IE, this throws a "not implemented" exception which most likely prevents other script from being run.

**Second**, `newamount` is not being defined anywhere.  The only place it's mentioned is in the `editamount` function:

```
function editamount() {
    changedamount=getAmount();
    var name=prompt("New Amount (Numbers ONLY):",changedamount);
    if (name != '' && name != null) {
        isNaN(newamount) ? changedamount : parseFloat(newamount);
        y.innerHTML="$"+nicenumber(newamount);
    }
    if (newamount != changedamount) { hideCalculated(); }
}
```

You need to add:

```
var newamount = ???;
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed it, so the error is not thrown out right away. But it gives an error as soon as I try to calculate something.

Comment: You get this error because `newamount` is not defined anywhere.  Where do you initialize it?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
newamount=parseFloat(name);
if (isNaN(newamount)) {
    newamount=changedamount;
}
```

with

```
isNaN(newamount) ? changedamount : parseFloat(newamount);
```

That makes it check for `NaN` before it does `parseFloat` which IE may have issues with.

Comment: changed. now it says: `object doesn't support this property or method: calculate`

Comment: this would then make it check whether a non-defined variable is a number...